# Get column names where searched value was found in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have query that performs full text search on several columns (including on columns of models related using FK) in Django:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank

class TaskManager(models.Manager):

    def search_by_text(self, text: str):
        search_vector = SearchVector(
            "task_type__name",
            "order__registration_number",
            "order__report_number",
            "car_owner_name",
            "task_number",
            "order__customer_order_number",
            "order__customer_owner",
            "order__report_type__value",
        )
        search_query = SearchQuery(text)
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(
            rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
        ).order_by("rank")
```

How can I get not only found records but also column names where searched value was found for each record? Example:

```py
>>> Entry.objects.search_by_text("some value")[0].columns_matched
["task_type__name", "task_number"]
```

I'm using Postgresql 10.12 and Django 2.2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by creating migration which creates database view which has `search_q` column containing concatenated string with values from all searched columns.

```sql
CREATE VIEW app_taskdata_search_view
AS
  SELECT Row_number()
           over(
             ORDER BY TASK.task_number) AS id,
         Concat(tasktype.name, '|', TASK.description, '|', USER.first_name, '|',
         USER.last_name)                AS search_q
  FROM   app_taskdata AS TASK
         inner join app_tasktype AS tasktype
                 ON TASK.task_type_id = tasktype.id
         inner join users_user AS USER
                 ON TASK.user_id = USER.id
  ORDER  BY TASK.task_number;
```

Then in `models.py`:

```py
class TaskDataSearchView(models.Model):
    """
    Database view refrenced from.
    """
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    search_q = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table= "app_taskdata_search_view"
        managed = False
```

Assuming I know the order of concatenated column values I can make a Python code which loops through result and checks if searched value was found in column:

```py
text = "Some text to search"
records = TaskDataSearchView.objects.filter(search_q__icontains=text)
values = records[0].search_q.split("|")
# check if task_type column contains searched text
if text in values[0]:
    field_mapping['task_type'] = True
```

P.S: Useful [link](https://resources.rescale.com/using-database-views-in-django-orm/)